# Shiny tabPanel and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, google-analytics, shiny

I've read myself through the great tutorial [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/google-analytics.html). However, my knowledge of jQuery equals to zero. I use several tabPanels in my ShinyApp to display my data. The tutorial explains how to track link-clicking events (which works fine, I included a .js as explained in the tutorial). Is there a way to track if users click on a specific tabPanel (for example `Panel1` and `Panel2`)? I've tried to do the same with a link referring to external sources, but that does not work.

```
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("Panel1", showOutput("PlotPanel1", 'dimple')),
tabPanel("Panel2", showOutput("PlotPanel2", 'dimple')))
```

**Edit:**

I guess I have to include some code in my analytics.js file. Therefore I tried several things, but frankly without knowledge of jQuery, this is just wrong. Can anyone help here?

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  on('option', 'click', function(l) {
  ga('send', 'event', 'tabPanel', 'tabPanel', $(l.currentTarget).val());
  }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I get it correctly what you would need as an output, you could do something like this (I don't use javascript):

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  #give an id to your tab in order to monitor it in the server
  tabsetPanel(id = 'tab123',
    tabPanel("Panel1", textOutput("PlotPanel1")),
    tabPanel("Panel2", textOutput("PlotPanel2"))
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  #now server can monitor the tabPanel through the id.
  #make the observer do whatever you want, e.g. print to a file
  observeEvent(input$tab123, {
    print(input$tab123)

    if (input$tab123 == 'Panel1') {
      sink(file = 'c:/Users/TB/Documents/panel1.txt', append = TRUE)
      cat(1)
      sink()
    } else {
      sink(file = 'c:/Users/TB/Documents/panel2.txt', append = TRUE)
      cat(1)
      sink()
    }

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Firstly, you give an id to your `tabsetPanel`. Now that server can access the tab data, you can create an event to observe using `observeEvent`. Every time a user clicks on each of the tabs, print will print the tab name on the console (this is for you to see what the variable `input$tab123` contains). Then you could do whatever you want with that information. Potentially, store it in a data base with a time stamp. In my example above, it creates two files in my documents, writing value 1 every time someone clicks on the tab. Then you just read the file in and sum the ones.

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me after tried so many different ways:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'TabsetPanel', 'Tab Viewed', $(this).attr('data-value'));
  });
```

though it will collect all the events related to *a*, but I guess only tabs have data-value, the rest of them will show as not set.