# Track user clicking on a tabPanel() in R Shiny application with Matomo

Tags: google-analytics, shinydashboard, shinyjs, matomo, event-tracking

I am trying to track tab-viewings for a R-Shiny application using Matomo. The tabs are created using tabPanel(). I have not found a solution yet that works. So far I have tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232499/shiny-tabpanel-and-google-analytics) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53384646/shinyjs-how-to-detect-if-a-user-clicked-on-a-tab).

I tried to insert this in the server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) { 

...

  observe({ 
    if(input$>tabsetPanelid< == ">tabPanelid<") {
      HTML("<script>
           _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
           _paq.push(['setDocumentTitle', '>test<']);
           </script>")
    }
  })

...

}
```

And I tried inserting this in the UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

...

    tags$script(
      HTML(
        "$(document).on('click', '>tabPanelid<', function(e) {
        ga('send', 'event', 'TabsetPanel', 'Tab Viewed', $(this).attr('data-value'));
        });"
      )
    ),

...

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is Matomo, but here is how to track the active tab.

When you do `tabsetPanel(tabPanel("THE TAB ID", tags$span(2)))`, this produces this HTML code:

```html
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabsetid="2677">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#tab-2677-1" data-toggle="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-value="THE TAB ID">THE TAB ID</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" data-tabsetid="2677">
    <div class="tab-pane active" data-value="THE TAB ID" id="tab-2677-1">
      <span>2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is some **Bootstrap 3** stuff. You have to listen to the event `shown.bs.tab` on the `<a>` elements with attribute `data-toggle="tab"`, and the tab id is in the `data-value` attribute. So here is how:

```js
$("a[data-toggle='tab']").on("shown.bs.tab", function(e) {
  var tabId = $(e.target).data("value");
  alert(tabId);
});
```

There are other tabs events:

```js
$("a[data-toggle='tab']")
  .on("show.bs.tab", function() {
  alert("New tab will be visible now");
}).on("shown.bs.tab", function() {
  alert("New tab is visible now");
}).on("hide.bs.tab", function() {
  alert("Previous tab will be hidden now");
}).on("hidden.bs.tab", function() {
  alert("Previous tab is hidden now");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @StéphaneLaurent. Matomo is very similar to Google Analytics. 
Could you give some more info on where you would put the Bootstrap 3 code in a R Shiny application? Do you need to wrap it in "tags$script(HTML())" in the UI? And what is the alert() supposed to produce as output?

Comment: @Rianne Bootstrap 3 is included in Shiny, there's nothing to add. `alert("hello")` pop-ups a window displaying "hello". This was just for the sake of an example.